# Form::password in Laravel Blade Templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I was trying to create a password field in the form in Laravel Blade templates but the output doesn't let me enter anything and it's not showing any placeholder either. The code doesn't cause any error.

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('class'=> 'forming')) }}
     {{ Form::text('username','Username',array('class' => 'insi')); }}<br>
     {{ Form::password('password',array('placeholder'=>'Password','class' => 'insi')); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and the output is like that. Any help?

[image: http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b503/darulehsan031/dddff_zps4f4ad69e.png]

Second Input form is for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not seeing your generated HTML, but usually those problems are related to your HTML. For instance, you are using a CSS class 'insi', which may not letting you see the password characters.

To do a test remove/disable your CSS files from your main HTML and it probably will work fine.

Comment: it worked but what about styling? how can i style it?

Comment: Should not be a problem, but are you using a styling framework or a template? You have a CSS problem and this is only solved via CSS, this is not a Laravel problem.

Comment: sir i want to syle my password input field, that class is working properly on text field but not on password field

Comment: I'll ask again: who wrote that CSS class? You? Or are you using a CSS framework or a template?

Comment: sir i wrote that class

Comment: So now you need help with the CSS you wrote. Create a new question (How can I fix this password box CSS?), tag it CSS, add to it the CSS you wrote and the HTML generated by Laravel, so people can see both, understand what's wrong with it and help you.